# Infinite, finitely generated subgroup of a group of homeomorphisms of closed unit disc

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Can we construct a finitely generated subgroup of infinite order of a group of homeomorphisms (which fix boundary point wise) of closed unit disc?

Comment: A group in which every finitely generated subgroup is finite is called "locally finite". A group in which every cyclic subgroup is finite is called "torsion" or "periodic". One has implications (locally finite) $\Rightarrow$ (torsion). As observed by John, one easily checks that the group you're considering is not torsion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the unit disc, in polar coordinates, 
$$
f_k(r, \theta) = (r, \theta + 2k\pi(1-r))
$$

Then 
$$
H = \{ f_k \mid k \in \Bbb Z \}
$$
is generated by $f_1$, and has infinite order.

Answer (score 2):

The disk $\Bbb D$  is topologically  the same as the upper half plane $\Bbb H$. Here we have for example
For every continuous $f\colon [0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ with $f(0)=0$, we have a homeomorphism
$$\phi_f\colon (x,y)\mapsto (x+f(y), y) $$
of $\Bbb H$ (with $\phi_f^{-1}=\phi_{-f}$). Also, for every continuous $g\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, we have a homeomorphism
$$\psi_g\colon (x,y)\mapsto (x,e^{g(x)}y) $$
of $\Bbb H$ (with $\psi_g^{-1}=\psi_{-g}$).
Now pick finitely many $\phi_f$'s and $\psi_g$'s and consider the group generated by them ...

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I got the idea.